# Making windows form maximize by default while not affecting UI

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

For being specific I just want how can I make window form by default maximized?
Now whenever I run my project it opens in a small window and when I maximize it, all the components are of the same size and at the exact same point which leaves other space empty so what is a solution for it?

Comment: See `anchor` in `Properties` window for each of your control.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Posts like *I just want to know how to...* are not asking a programming question.  That is asking for a tutorial which is too broad for this site.

Comment: I think that this is just about on topic as questions about the ide are just about ok :-)

Answer (score 2):

To have the form maximized every time it loads, just add the following line to your `.Load` event

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

or, using the ide at design time, click any empty space on the form, and in the properties window down on the right, set WindowState to Maximised.